# Python calling a function from imported module causes permission error

Tags: python, powershell

I wanted to use PowerShell command through Python so I got this function

Functions.py:

```py
import subprocess as sp

def makeconnection():
    proc = sp.Popen('powershell add-vpnconnection ...my credentials...', stdout= sp.PIPE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    makeconnection()
```

Main.py:

```py
from Functions import makeconnection


#...Codes...
    try:
        appdatapath = os.getenv('appdata')
        with open(appdatapath + r'\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk', "r+") as f:

            if f.read().find('CookieVPN') != -1:
                print("VPN Connection: OK")
            else:
                #1. This code doesn't work
                makeconnection()
                #2. Then if I replace the line above with this one it works
                proc = sp.Popen('powershell add-vpnconnection ...my credentials...', stdout=sp.PIPE)

                print("VPN Connection: Created")

    except Exception as e:
        print('\n\nSomething went wrong while accessing the connection\n' + '-' * 15)
        print(e)
        input('\n\n   *** Press Enter To Exit ***')
        sys.exit()
#...Rest of the Codes...
```

It
 works fine on its own but if I import this into another .py file and call it from there it raises the "permission denied" error from PowerShell.

What causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please share the code how you are importing from another file and running? It is a file permission issue of course!

Comment: `subporcess` in the code you posted should be `subprocess`, but since you say the code you posted works by itself I suppose that is just a typo in your question. Please [edit] your question and fix it anyway, b/c it's not helpful when code in a question introduces new bugs not existing in the original code.

Comment: With that said, if you want us to help with code that isn't working you need to show us the code that isn't working as well as how you run it and the full error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I added the main code and fixed some of the typos. Since some parts are entered by hand it may contain typos but I did my best to avoid any typo.

Comment: Please don't paraphrase. Copy/paste the full output of your script into your question.

Comment: Well, I will recreate the problem and will update the post since I changed my code to work.

Comment: I don't know why but it seems the problem is not occurring in a new project and I don't have access to the previous codes so I think maybe it was a faulty code in the program. I will update this page if I can get to recreate the issue.